# Mic works in sound recorder but in nothing else

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone

Mic only works in sound recorder and although it works there its just a bunch of static underneath the spoken word, but audible. In skype, cheese, and using "arecord test.wav" at the terminal, it's the same static/white noise with nothing I'm saying being recorded. I'm using a Gateway LT2016U (KAV60?) and not sure where to begin. Tweaking alsamixer yields no result, but if it works in one app shouldn't it work in all?

Comment: this is the built in mic on the netbook btw

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

try switching from asla or pulseaudio to oss open up terminal and type
gstreamer-properties and it should pull up a config box to change sound settings

Comment: I couldn't use OSS, *but* I did find this helpful. My sound input was defaulting to the mobo sound input (which is unconnected), and I was able to switch to my webcam mic.

Comment: Also I just realized the "G" in gstreamer is for Gnome... On Kubuntu I also found it useful to go into the Multimedia control panel and disable my onboard audio, and then "prefer" the webcam audio.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: There might be a second microphone connector on your mainboard which you need to turn off. Check the "input" page of the audio-settings.

Comment: there's analong input and analog microphone, I've tried both neither are working. No way to turn one off over the other just a way to select em.